# Export Tables from Microsoft MySQL Server Management Studio with Insert Statements

Tags: mysql, backup

I have a database on a school server that I have limited access to, so I cannot import a data backup like I would like to.  I only need one table, and I am wondering if there is a way to create a file from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to create the table then insert all the data (talking about 23,000 rows, so quite a bit to move otherwise).

I have the database backup imported into a schema on my copy of Microsoft MySQL Server, just not on the school server that I would like to be using.

If anyone has a better way of doing it, I am very open to suggestions.

EDIT: Just so everyone has an idea of what I'm working with on the school side, it is a limited version of phpmyadmin:

[image: example]

Import is limited to sql script files.

Comment: what do you mean by limited access? can you read that data? can you copy that data to some excel file?

Comment: Not really sure how to describe it.  Limited in that we have to use their interface portal, which allows you to run scripts but with no access to the server itself.

Comment: it allows import of sql files, but not .bak files.

Comment: MySQL or SQL server which one? PLease clarify.